# Capitalized "JPG" extension different from lowercase "jpg"?

Tags: html, jpeg

I am working on a personal webpage, a draft version of which I have uploaded to www.kurtpeek.com. One of the bugs I notice, is that one of my jpeg images in the "About Me" section, "MIT_IAP_SAR_smallest.JPG", does not show up on the web, but I can see it just fine if I look at it on my computer. (You can download the directory from http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1396332/kurtpeek.com.rar ).

The only difference I can see with the other pictures is that this one has a capitalized ".JPG" extension instead of a lowercase ".jpg" one. However, if I try to rename the file to a lowercase extension Windows 7 just capitalizes it again.

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

Best regards,
Kurt Peek

P.S. This problem seems similar to this one:

[php file upload capitalized filename issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987775/php-file-upload-capitalized-filename-issue)

but as far as I can tell that problem was not resolved.

Comment: Extensions should be meaningless, and it's not a CMYK image (which don't work in IE).... Can you show a live example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very likely that your server is running under a Linux distribution, whose [file system is usually case-sensitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Features).

- http://www.kurtpeek.com/img/MIT_IAP_SAR_smallest.jpg - Not found
- http://www.kurtpeek.com/img/MIT_IAP_SAR_smallest.JPG - Found

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks, I somehow managed to rename the picture to a lowercase ".jpg" extension after all and now I can see it on the web as well. (Incidentally, this problem was also addressed at http://allwebco-templates.com/support/S_images_not_updating.htm).

Comment: Assuming the trouble is because of a Linux server's case sensitivity, one trick (particularly useful if for some reason you can't update the file name to match the link or the link to match the file name) is to make the server relax on the case sensitivity. You can do that either in the Apache config, or .htaccess - see [.htaccess or other URL Case Sensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270772/htaccess-or-other-url-case-sensitive). For more, try the search terms "case insensitive"

Comment: You can batch rename your files on windows in command prompt. Just use:  "forfiles /S /M *.JPG /C "cmd /c rename @file @fname.jpg"