# HTML distinction .jpg .JPG

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I'm building a website hosted on Github Pages that has a gallery that sources a lot of images from a folder. I keep running into two problems:

1) I upload a picture and Github automatically rotates it?

2) HTML wont find the image if I reference it as say "example.jpg" when it is saved as "example.JPG". Less of a question, just looking for insight into why theres a distinction when capitalized.

Comment: maybe the `toLowerCase()` helps?

Comment: It's very likely that the picture is actually stored as Github Pages shows it but the camera is using [file metadata](https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html) to indicate it actually needs to be rotated on display. Software that's not aware of such metadata will not display it properly (that used to include major browsers, not sure if it changed).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to probably just manually edit (rotate/align) the photos in your computers builtin photo software.

As for the image extension, if you're running into problems with file extension capitalization then just go with what works. Change all extensions to either one uppercase or lower case would make the most sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Linux's file system is case sensitive; but in general, a best practice I follow is to point to what the URL is vs. what I want/like it to be.
[Reference to another similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433945/capitalized-jpg-extension-different-from-lowercase-jpg#9434051)

[Here are the instructions to edit/add images to GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-images-to-wikis/)